# Fetch only local branches by default?

Tags: git

So, I have a repository that has a large number of remote branches. Pulling down all of these branches takes a long time and uses a lot of space.

What I'd like to do is, by default, only pull references that correspond to local branches.

I can sort-of accomplish this by changing the default git config from something like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

to

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
    # additional fetch lines for other branches that should be fetched
```

but this has the unfortunate side effect that if I push a new branch with `--set-upstream`, it doesn't automatically add a remote ref (in refs/remotes/origin), and doesn't fetch that branch as part of a `git fetch`. Also, `git status` no longer reports on the status compared to the upstream remote branch, even if the reference for the remote actually exists.

Is there a better way to do this, or to automatially add refspec to the `remote.*.fetch` config when creating new branches?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a refspec from the command line :

```
git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/newbranch:refs/remotes/origin/newbranch
```

You can use this for example to create a shortcut :

```
git config alias.rfspec '! f () { git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/$1:refs/remotes/origin/$1; }; f'

# usage :
git rfspec new/branch
```

or include it in a more elaborate script, which would for example create the refspec and push in one go :

```
# in file git-pushnew :

#!/bin/bash

# first argument is branch :
br="$1"
if [ -z "$br" ]; then
# set default to : current active branch
    br=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
fi

# add the refspec for this branch :
git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/$br:refs/remotes/origin/$br
# push this specific branch to origin :
git push -u origin $br
```

If you set this file as executable, and it is accessible from your `PATH`, you can type :

```
git pushnew
# or
git pushnew that/branch
```

You may create a `git-fetchnew` script in a similar way, which would fetch and add to the refspec a specific branch.

Comment: Slightly simpler, though it still needs some scripting, is to use `git remote set-branches --add` (which builds the `remote.origin.fetch` line for you and calls `git config --add` appropriately).